# NodeJS express Change value in json

Tags: node.js, json, express

excuse me, I am a beginner at nodejs express, I want to ask how do I change the data in the response json from

the date format 2017-12-14T05: 23: 01.000Z
to the date format  dd / mm / yyyy

and that I mean when it is issued as a response json key with the name "TANGGAL_PEMBAYARAN" changes to dd / mm / yyyy?

this is my json response

```
{
"result": {
    "STATUS": "Y",
    "TANGGAL_PEMBAYARAN": "2017-12-14T05:23:01.000Z",
    "NTPD": "1110374001101224",
    "JENIS_BAYAR": "T"
}
```

thank you very much

Comment: You should continue to use ISO 8602 because it will be parsed correctly by web-browsers, whereas localized formats will not. Is there a reason you want to use a localised format?

Comment: yes i hv any reason to localise format, cause this response consume by another soft tool

Answer (score 1):

We can use [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to format as dd/mm/yyyy, for example a en-GB locale will do this.

We can also specify a timeZone (in this example I'm using UTC)

You could also use Moment.js or Luxon to do this conversion.

```js
let response = {
    "result": {
        "STATUS": "Y",
        "TANGGAL_PEMBAYARAN": "2017-12-14T05:23:01.000Z",
        "NTPD": "1110374001101224",
        "JENIS_BAYAR": "T"
    }
};

function isoDateToLocaleDateString(isoDate, locale, timeZone) {
    return new Date(isoDate).toLocaleDateString(locale, { timeZone } );
}

// Convert date format
response.result.TANGGAL_PEMBAYARAN = isoDateToLocaleDateString(response.result.TANGGAL_PEMBAYARAN, "en-GB", "UTC")
console.log("Response date:", response.result.TANGGAL_PEMBAYARAN);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , already solved im using day.js

Answer (score 1):

You can use momentjs (https://momentjs.com/)

```
const moment = require('moment'); 

let response = {
"result": {
    "STATUS": "Y",
    "TANGGAL_PEMBAYARAN": "2017-12-14T05:23:01.000Z",
    "NTPD": "1110374001101224",
    "JENIS_BAYAR": "T"
}

response.result.TANGGAL_PEMBAYARAN = moment(response.result.TANGGAL_PEMBAYARAN).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
```